# Предупреждение при сборке проекта в xCode 12.3 для Debug: отсутствует кэш модуля Foundation-3ONTK7DIWRW8K.pcm

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Появилось данное предупреждение после манипуляций с расположением папки DerivedData. Вот полный текст предупреждения:

warning: /Users/aduo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/3C3EQCYN6GZGH/Foundation-3ONTK7DIWRW8K.pcm: No such file or directory
note: while processing /Users/aduo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/3C3EQCYN6GZGH/Foundation-3ONTK7DIWRW8K.pcm
note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the module cache was not found.  Redistributable static libraries should never be built with module debugging enabled.  The debug experience will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.

Предупреждение исчезает, если для режима Debug выставить настройку DWARF вместо DWARF with dSYM File. Но тогда появляется сообщение о необходимости вернуть DWARF with dSYM для всех конфигураций, иначе возникнут проблемы с FireBaseCrashlytics.

Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите как избавиться от этих предупреждений.

Comment: А на работу они как-то влияют?

Comment: Нет, не влияют. Но раздражает наличие 20-ти warnings при компиляции проекта...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно что-то тянется из кеша, который ностальгирует по старой папке DerivedData, если до этого все было нормально.

Попробуйте пройтись стандартным набором:

- Очистить DerivedData (и старое расположение заодно).
- pod deintegrate.
- pod update.
- rebuild.
- вернуть DerivedData как было.